# Different result from regex in Windows vs linux?

Tags: python, regex, linux, python-2.7

I have slapped together some code for project that requires a match a the beginning of file names.  Below is the code that has been working in Windows.

```
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(up_path):
    files.sort()
    total_files += len(files)
    print total_files
    for fn in files:
        print fn
        filename_zero, extension = os.path.splitext(fn)
        path2 = os.path.join(root, fn)
        ID = re.match('^/d{1,10}', fn).group()
        print ID
```

In windows, if a  file was named `1234567-1.jpg`, the result from the print ID would be `1234567`.
However, in Linux I am getting a `Nonetype error`, where the print ID returns `NONE`.
I know what this suggests, that there is no match and therefore no ID is generated.
Since the only difference is moving from Windows to Linux, what are the different requirements between two systems?
How can I make this work as intended?

Comment: Your code cannot match anything in Windows either, as `/d{1,10}` matches a literal forward slash and between 1 and 10 `d` characters. Since `fn` is a filename without directory path, there won't ever be a slash in that name.

Comment: @MartijnPieters where he put slash in the filename?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: the slash is in the *pattern*. It can never *be* in the filename.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it would be better if you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj your answer is plenty. I'm merely addressing the claim this worked on Windows, which it cannot have.

Comment: I am afraid that I am a victim of my own stupid shortcut(find and replace).  @MartijnPieters you are absolutely right, should have seen that my Windows code had the appropriate slash.  Hours of staring at the same code rendered me a tad myopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error , it's not `/d` it's `\d`, so your code would be,

```
ID = re.match('^\d{1,10}', fn).group()
```

`\d` matches a digit ie, `[0-9]`

Comment: Haha.  Sometimes another pair of eyes is all you need.  Thanks

Comment: Short and sweet, +1 :)